# Can an imported node module call a function which was initialized in the main module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, scope, export

I wrote a module to contain some of the less interesting bits of a large Javascript codebase I am working on, call it `boring.js`.

It is imported from a main module that does most of the more interesting work, call it `main.js`.

There is a class in `boring.js` called `Log`, which is exported to `main.js` and instantiated to a variable `log`. Calling the function `log.save(newLogMsg)` saves `newLogMsg` to file.

`log.save(newLogMsg)` works fine when called from `main.js`

When I try to call `log.save(newLogMsg)` from inside a function that resides in `boring.js`, I get the error:

`ReferenceError: log is not defined`

Which is confusing to me, because `let log = new Log` is initialized in the main module before I call the function in question (from `main.js`) that resides inside the imported module.

**Side Question:** Why can I call `console.log(newLogMsg)` from any module that I choose? How could I go about implementing a similar functionality for my `Log` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An imported module cannot access the namespace of the module that imports it.

Say you have a module named `module.js` that looks like this:

```js
// module.js
exports.x = 10;
```

And a script `main.js` that imports it:

```js
// main.js
const s = "abc";
const m = require('./module');
```

Here is what happens when running `main.js`:

- Line 1: the string `"abc"` is mapped to the name `s` in the main namespace
- Line 2: the `require` function executes the script named `module.js` and
  returns its `export` object. The script runs in its own scope and doesn't
  know anything about the script which is importing it. Therefore it cannot
  see the constant `s` defined in `main.js`
- Line 2: the return value of require (the module's `export` object) is
  assigned to the constant `m` defined inside `main.js`

About your side question:

- you could pass the `log` object as a parameter to a function defined
  inside `module.js`
- you can define `log` in a third module and require it both from `main.js` and from `module.js`